# Angular 4 with Firebase. How to make random ID?

Tags: angular, firebase

It`s like I make title 'some stuff' and It should make it some-stuff-H5KNWGFGHNWG2(random firebaseId).

What I need to add to my doc chain to make it work?

Is there some random id method like fb.randomId()?

```
    this.db.collection('posts')
        .doc(this.title.split(' ').join('-') + '-')
          .set({'title': this.title, 'content': this.content});
```

UPD: To better understanding of what I what.

```
.doc(this.title.split(' ').join('-') + '-'+Some random Id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the random id from firestore before its been pushed

```
let id = this.db.createId();
```

now you can `.doc(this.title.split(' ').join('-') + '-'+id).set({...});`